# How do I proxy pass a URL in Nginx where location match is a URL and proxy pass has another URL

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass, url-routing

We have hosted some xml files in a S3 bucket on Amazon AWS. The web server is powered by Nginx. For a particular URL matching '/super-shots.xml' , Nginx must proxy pass through  S3 location which is : http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/depth0/depth1/depth2/sitemap.xml

What I want is this (Nginx Config):

```
location ~* /super-shots.xml {
    proxy_pass http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/depth0/depth1/depth2/sitemap.xml;
}
```

Result is an error:

> nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by
>   regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if"
>   statement, or inside "limit_except" block

If I do not do a regular expression match (~*|~), then there is no syntax errors, but the page returns 404. Note that the file does not exists on system path.

I have tried looking around for solution, but most of deal with path as a match. How do I work around this?

For now, I have done a path based proxy-pass which works (given below). But, I want it with the URL match.

```
#Nginx Config:
location  /super-shots {
    proxy_pass http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/depth0/depth1/depth2/sitemap.xml;
}

# On file system : Empty directory
mkdir $docroot/depth0/depth1/depth2/

nginx -s reload
```

Update 1:
Based on Alexey Ten's comment.
Sample of the Nginx Configuration can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15000876/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried simple?

```
location = /super-shots.xml {
    proxy_pass http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/depth0/depth1/depth2/sitemap.xml;
}
```

You don't need anything on local file system.

Your problem is that request `/super-shot.xml` matches `location ~* \.(js|ico|...xml...`.
Using `=` suffix we tell nginx that this exact request should be processed here and it must not look for other possible matching locations.

Comment: I tried that.   The page is 404 (server : nginx) !
It doesn't proxy_pass at all.

Comment: @anup then you must show full nginx config

Comment: A sample configuration file can be found here:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/15000876/       I had to alter domain name and remove rewrite rules (I assure that no rewrite rules matches the one in question).   Nginx --  version: nginx/1.4.5

Comment: Put it into your post

Comment: I updated answer

Comment: Argh !  Such a silly miss !

Thanks a ton @alexey-ten